# How to run a mouse on android 7.1 (TV Box)?

Tags: 7.1-nougat, usb-drivers, mouse

I got gifted a nice **wireless mouse** this morning.
I've seen android work with a mouse before so I figured it can handle it as a plug an play, given that this one doesn't have fancy buttons that can be configured - hence needing special software.

Well that wasn't the case, and the manufacturer of the mouse doesn't have android drivers.

Is there such a thing as a general mouse driver I could find. If windows while offline can give basic functions to a new mouse, can we give a helping hand to android to jump the gap?

Normally I'd just go to the store and swap it for a Bluetooth mouse but its a friendly gift and I don't want to do that unless i have to.

The tech is "96 pro plus" tv box (has two usb ports) runs a cable mouse with no problem.

(Just returned it and got a bluetooth replacement in the end)

Comment: please provide more information. are you talking about amazon fire tv stick? Is it a bluetooth mouse or a WiFi mouse with/without usb dongle?

Comment: h96 pro plus tv box (has a usb port) and wifi mouse. The mouse mouse is named in the fifth word of the original post come on  :)

Comment: according to the specification the H96 Pro Plus Smart TV Box has USB-OTG support. just plug in the usb dongle which comes with your mouse

Comment: Did you seriously think that I didn't try and came asking for a driver before I even tried the mouse? It has enough usb capability to use a thumb drive, but apparently not enough for a mouse.

Comment: you would not believe what questions asked here daily. for android there are no such things like drivers (not at consumer level, at least). Newer android devices usually come with usb-otg support. for mobiles a usb-otg adapter is required. the adapter requests the device to interact in host mode (by short-circuiting pins 4+5). Assuming your Smart TV Box already has this inside, no adapter is required in your case. Try cable mouse instead for testing purposes

Comment: A cable mouse is working fine.

Comment: please check if the WiFi mouse is working on PC. Maybe there is a switch you missed, or batteries are empty. There is nothing you can do from android side. for mobiles there is sometimes external power supply required, which should not the case for TV box (for mobiles use this charging hub: https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07JZND95Z )

Comment: I did, before posting the thread. Its was operational on pc. I guess im trading it in for a Bluetooth one after all. Still the box was worth the money. I would have spent 5 times that for a smart tv that would have been dumber in the end.